# SceneKit, shader to overlay color based on world coordinates to node based

Tags: scenekit, fragment-shader

I have simple shader which allows me to redraw node color based on the local axises of the node (x > 0) -> green, but how to make it works based on the world coordinates.

(possible shader based not by converting some points from scene and passing it to shader)

[Shader demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxA1i.png)

```
vec4 pos = u_inverseModelTransform * u_inverseViewTransform * vec4(_surface.position, 1.0);

if (pos.x > 0.0) {
    _output.color.rgb = vec3(0.0, 0.8, 0.0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't want to multiply by `u_inverseModelTransform` which moves you back from world space to object space.

```
vec4 pos = u_inverseViewTransform * vec4(_surface.position, 1.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

As a corollary to ‘mnuages’ correct answer, I finally figured out that if you’re in MetalSL and not GLSL you should use `scn_frame.inverseViewTransform` not `u_inverseViewTransform`.

This is tricky because SceneKit will automatically try to cross-compile GLSL shaderModifiers into MetalSL so it’s hard to know which one you’re using sometimes. (E.g., you can have your SceneKit view be Metal-backed instead of OpenGL- or GLES-backed and still write your shader modifiers in GLSL and SceneKit will work.)